# Kitchen EC2 on Windows - Eventual WinRM::WinRMAuthorizationError

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I am using the Kitchen EC2 driver for testing some Windows "base" cookbooks on Windows Server 2012R2, 2016, and 1803 AMIs from Amazon. I'm encountering what seems like a problem that happens after a specific duration of time while executing a recipe via Kitchen, as opposed to hitting a specific line of code.

At some point during the recipe converge it stops with a WinRM::WinRMAuthorizationError. If I rerun the converge it immediately boots me out with the same error. I've tried changing and moving resources in the recipe, and it seems like it isn't a problem with a specific part of the recipe, it just happens randomly and then continues to happen.

This started because I'm trying to remove our custom user-data script, and instead use the one that the Kitchen-EC2 driver generates. They are *roughly* the same, but they just do things in slightly different ways.

I'm planning to do more troubleshooting ([this](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/understanding-and-troubleshooting-winrm-connection-and-authentication-a-thrill-seekers-guide-to-adventure) seems like a good resource) but given that I'm trying to use vanilla settings, I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious.

Relevant part of the `.kitchen.yml`:

```
transport:
  name: 'winrm'
  elevated: true
  username: 'Administrator'
  ssh_key: ~/.ssh/test-kitchen
```

Default user-data:

```bsh
# Logic for determining $logfile is removed...
$logfile='C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Logs\kitchen-ec2.log'

# Allow script execution
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force

# PS Remoting and & winrm.cmd basic config
Enable-PSRemoting -Force -skipnetworkprofilecheck

& winrm.cmd set winrm/config '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}' >> $logfile
& winrm.cmd set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="1024"}' >> $logfile
& winrm.cmd set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxShellsPerUser="50"}' >> $logfile
& winrm.cmd set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="1024"}' >> $logfile

# Firewall Config
& netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" profile=public protocol=tcp localport=5985 remoteip=localsubnet new remoteip=any  >> $logfile
Set-ItemProperty -Name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy -Path HKLM:\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system -Value 1
```

Comment: @ Jason Capriotti - I hit the same problem. Did you find any solution to this ?

Comment: @srinannapa I just added an answer based on my experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is this had to do with the AMI I was using, which was a [CIS](https://www.cisecurity.org/) image.

More specifically, I think the userdata script did work for initial WinRM authorization. But some of the CIS AMI group policies that conflict with the `winrm.cmd` commands in the userdata were *possibly* later applied and that killed the connection. My thought is that running `gpupdate` later as part of the normal recipe was reapplying them.

I think running these commands these in userdata was what helped. It requires installing module that contains the `Set-PolicyFileEntry` command.

```
Set-PolicyFileEntry -Path $MachineDir -Key Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Client -ValueName AllowBasic -Data 1 -Type DWord  
Set-PolicyFileEntry -Path $MachineDir -Key Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Service -ValueName AllowBasic -Data 1 -Type DWord 
Set-PolicyFileEntry -Path $MachineDir -Key Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile -ValueName EnableFirewall -Data 0 -Type DWord 
Set-PolicyFileEntry -Path $MachineDir -Key Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile -ValueName EnableFirewall -Data 0 -Type DWord 
Set-PolicyFileEntry -Path $MachineDir -Key Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PrivateProfile -ValueName EnableFirewall -Data 0 -Type DWord 
Set-PolicyFileEntry -Path $MachineDir -Key Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -ValueName LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy -Data 1 -Type DWord 

gpupdate
```